# Compute all roots of $(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

$$(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

The problem states to compute all roots of the complex number above. Below is my attempt, but my inquiries are if I did it right and why it doesn't match [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-8%29%5E%7B1%2F3%7D). Wolfram only returns $1$ result - was I only supposed to have $1$ as well??

$$\text{modulus} = 8$$
$$\theta = \arctan \left(\frac{0}{-8}\right) = 0$$

Because we are working in the left half of the complex plane, $\theta=\pi$.

$$z=\left(8e^{i(2\pi k+\pi)}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

This complex number has $3$ roots, so $k=0,1,2$ :

$$z_0=2e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$$
$$z_1=2e^{i\pi}$$
$$z_2=2e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}}$$

Comment: You don't want to use `{}` in wolfram, see [this wolfram result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-8%29^%281%2F3%29)

Comment: @KristofferRyhl Why not? Your link has the same result + alternatives as my link. The rest of the page is different, sure, but what is the difference in regards to the answers for the root values?

Comment: Braces like `{}` specify you are denoting a set with multiple elements. This way, you can do multiple computations in one command with Wolfram Alpha. For example, here's [Wolfram Alpha adding 2 to 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 all at the same time](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2B%7B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%7D). However, since your set only has one element, using the braces is useless and while Wolfram Alpha still shows the answer, it does not show all of the information that @KristofferRyhl 's page shows.

Comment: @NobleMushtak makes sense. I'll make a mental note. It was just a habit of using this site :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve:

$$z^3=-8\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^3=|-8|e^{\arg(-8)i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^3=8e^{\pi i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\left(8e^{\left(2\pi k+\pi\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=2e^{\frac{1}{3}\left(2\pi k+\pi\right)i}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-2$

---

So the solutions are:

$$z_0=2e^{\frac{1}{3}\left(2\pi\cdot0+\pi\right)i}=2e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$$
$$z_1=2e^{\frac{1}{3}\left(2\pi\cdot1+\pi\right)i}=2e^{\pi i}=-2$$
$$z_2=2e^{\frac{1}{3}\left(2\pi\cdot2+\pi\right)i}=2e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}}$$

Comment: Wait why isn't your $z_2 = 2e^{\frac{i5\pi} {3}}$ ?

Comment: Thats the same!!

Comment: But should my answers all lie within the same range of theta values, e.g. $(\pi, \pi]$ or something? I feel as though that while yes, they are the same *in a way*, it would be **more correct** to write it the way you did. And I'm also not sure if my professor would knock off some points for writing it the way I wrote it. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are solving and the problem Wolfram Alpha is solving are different problems.

You want to find all of the roots of $x^3+8=0$ which you did corrrectly. Your three solutions are all of the solutions to that equation.

However, you asked Wolfram Alpha to take $-8$ to the $1/3$ power. That's a different problem because there, you're not solving a polynomial equation. Instead, you're taking one number to the power of a fractional number. When you take a number to the power of another number, there is only one clearly defined answer even if the power is fractional. For example, $2^{\frac 1 2}$ is $\sqrt 2$, the principal (positive) square root of 2, and that's different from $-\sqrt 2$. Similarly, $(-8)^{\frac 1 3}$ is the "principal" cube root of $-8$ and must be $2e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ because out of all of the solutions to $x^3+8=0$, that solution has the lowest argument.

If you want to find all of the solutions to $x^3+8=0$, [tell Wolfram Alpha to do that instead](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3%2B8%3D0). As you can see, Wolfram Alpha now has three answers like you do, but has expressed them in rectangular form rather than polar form like you did. However, your answers and Wolfram Alpha's answers are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

We can use elementary factorization to find all roots. Let $x = \left(-8\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\Rightarrow x^3 = -8\Rightarrow x^3 + 8 = 0\Rightarrow (x+2)(x^2-2x+4) = 0\Rightarrow (x+2)((x-1)^2 + 3) = 0\Rightarrow x = -2, (x-1)^2 = -3\Rightarrow x = -2, x-1 = \pm i\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow x = -2, 1 \pm i\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Ok yea, I had a feeling that my answer was wrong. After I finished it I took a step back and said wait a minute, intuitively I know that one of the roots of $-8$ must be $-2$. Do you know where I might have gone wrong? We are learning about complex numbers so I need to improve my understanding of how to use the method I used above (or something relatively similar) to find the roots of any given complex number. So my professor would probably knock off some points for using elementary factorization :(

Comment: Wait actually, I did get $-2$. Because $e^{i\pi} = -1$!

Comment: For this question, you just apply definition of taking cube root of a complex number and rewrite it in polar form. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

It “seems” we can just say x = –2 because (– 2)^3 = –8 but – 2 is not the Primary or Principal Solution!

Using De Moivre’s theorem again:
x^3 =  – 8
( r cis(θ) )^3 = –8
r^3 cis(3θ)   = 8cis( 180 + 360n)
r^3 = 8   and   3θ = 180 + 360n
r = 2    and    θ = 60 + 120n = 60, 180, 300

x1  =  2cis( 60 ) = 1 + i√3
x2  = 2cis(180) =  – 2
x3  = 2cis(300) =  1 – i√3

The Primary Solution is x1 = 1 + i√3   ≈ 1 + 1.732i
So cube root of -8  or (-8)^(1/3)=1+1.732i    and NOT-2!